# error al utilizar Enum en JAVA

Tags: java, enum

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seguro sea un error muy bobo..

Comment: Quizá si declaras tu variable como `public enum Provincia ...` desaparezca el problema... no se aprecia bien, pero parece que quieres usarla en un método en cuyo ámbito la variable no existe... Para futuros preguntas, no olvides este principio: **en Stackoverflow, un código vale más que mil imágenes**. Si compartes el texto del código comentando dónde está el error y cuál es el error, será de más utilidad que la imagen.

Comment: A. Cedano, me sorprende que un usuario con más de 18.000 puntos de una respuesta tan vaga, aunque la mayor parte de los puntos sean en PHP. Si no sabes como funcionan los modificadores de acceso, quizás sería mejor no responder, para evitar confundir a la gente que está intentando aprender de lo que se publica aquí. Para que entiendas mejor a qué me refiero te pongo aquí una referencia a la documentación de Oracle que tiene para los modifcadores de acceso.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @MarioCastillo a pesar de que considero que tienes razón y el problema no es del modificador de acceso, no me parece necesario ser tan agresivo en tu comentario. Para empezar, A. Cedano no ha puesto una respuesta, sino un comentario (cuya primera parte es efectivamente incorrecta), pero bastaba con aclararlo respetuosamente sin hacer referencia a su reputación. Todos podemos equivocarnos y estoy seguro de que si hubieras sido tu agradecerías que se te corrigiera con educación. Un saludo.

Comment: No me había planteado siquiera que le hubiese faltado al respeto por hacer referencia a su reputación o algo por el estilo. Si es verdad que mi comentario se puede considerar un tanto agresivo, pero no me sale otra forma de decir las cosas. Si he ofendido a @A.Cedano me disculpo ya que en ningún momento era esa mi intención, de verdad. He de añadir en mi defensa que llevo un par de días haciendo uso activo de esta plataforma y aunque me hayan explicado bastante de como funciona, es cierto que me puedo haber equivocado al expresarme así, no lo se. De todas formas, intentare corregirlo. Gracias.

Comment: @MarioCastillo como dije antes, todos podemos equivocarnos. Te honra disculparte y por supuesto por mi parte darte la bienvenida y espero que sigas aportando a la comunidad ya que es muy necesario tener cuantos mas usuarios mejor. Y si tienes cualquier duda, puedes visitar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) o hacer uso de [meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Como ya indicó Pikoh, @MarioCastillo, no he dado una respuesta, observé el código e hice un comentario rápido. Por si no lo sabes, los comentarios pueden ser usados para intentar respuestas rápidas que el OP probará y si no funciona revertirá el código a como lo tenía al principio. La intención no es *confundir* a nadie. De todos modos considero que tu respuesta tampoco es coherente del todo. Si te fijas, él recibe en `PromocionLocal` la variable `prov` en parámetro... la respuesta que das puede confundir mucho más que mi comentario. ¿Si es visible en la clase, por qué recibirla en parámetro?

Comment: Como dije en el comentario anterior, me disculpo si lo que he dicho te ha ofendido @A.Cedano. También explique que no se mucho sobre esta plataforma, estoy de prueba! El caso es que aunque intento ponerme en tu lugar, no se qué quieres decir. No consigo encontrar mucho sentido. No he afirmado que tu intención sea confundir a nadie. Mi respuesta es coherente con respecto a la pregunta que se hizo, ¿En qué crees que no lo es?¿Por si la función se usa fuera del paquete? Es tan simple como que no he querido dar por hecho cosas que no son. Esa pregunta debería ir para Cosoforo Decimo. Un abrazo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar `SALTA` por `Provincia.SALTA` en la línea 32, y a establecer `Provincia` (el enum) como `public`.

EDITO: Establecer `Provincia` como `public` no es necesario para corregir el error concreto que se muestra en la imagen (como bien indica Mario Castillo en su respuesta), pero actualmente hay una discrepancia entre la accesibilidad del método `PromocionLocal` (que es `public`) y la de uno de sus parámetros: `prov`, que es de tipo `Provincia`, que es menos accesible que el método. El problema causado por esa discrepancia se visibilizará el día en que intentes invocar el método desde fuera del package `casaempanadas`. Dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo, arreglar el detalle de una vez puede parecerte más o menos necesario, pero sin duda es mala idea dejar *smells* o *bugs* por ahí.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a explicar por qué te está ocurriendo este error, que como bien dices es una cosa bien sencilla.

En la línea 32 intentas hacer uso del valor `SALTA` del `enum` `Provincia`. Al menos eso es lo que interpreto que has intentado hacer. El fallo es muy sencillo, no puedes acceder a un elemento de un `enum` sin referenciarlo. Sí indicas directamente `SALTA`, no se puede encontrar como una variable. Si te fijas te lo pone claramente:

```
Cannot find symbol
Symbol: variable SALTA
```

Para solucionar este tema no es necesario que añadas el modificador de acceso `Public` al enum Provincias, ya que está usando el modificador de acceso "Package-Private". Este modificador le da acceso a todos los elementos que están en su paquete, pero no a los que estan en niveles superiores. Te lo digo porque te han recomendado cambiarlo a `Public` cuando eso no va a cambiar nada, ya que el `enum` `Provincias` sí está accesible desde la clase `CasaEmpanadas`. Como iba diciendo, lo único que tienes que hacer es añadir la referencia al `enum` `Provincias`, te lo pongo en código para que lo veas.

Antes:

```
System.out.println(PromocionLocal(SALTA, 20, 20));
```

Despues:

```
System.out.println(PromocionLocal(Provincia.SALTA, 20, 20));
```

Con este cambio el error que nos has mostrado en pantalla se debería arreglar, pero no se puede asegurar que sea el único error, ya que no has puesto más que una captura de pantalla del código, y una descripción muy deficiente.

Comment: Acerca del public del enum: ¿qué pasaría si se quisiera llamar al método "PromocionLocal" (que es public, de una clase public) desde fuera del package "casaempanadas"?

Comment: Simple! no tendría visibilidad para el tipo de dato que de requiere para el primer parámetro, por lo tanto no se podría usar dicho método bajo esas circunstancias, sería necesario cambiarle el modificador de acceso al enum Provincias. Es mas, sería recomendable sacarlo del fichero en el que se encuentra, y ponerlo por separado en el pqquete que tenga más sentido. He hecho hincapie en que el modificador public no era necesario porque con lq definicion y el código que tenemos es así.

Comment: Tenemos entonces una discrepancia entre la visibilidad del método y la visibilidad del tipo de uno de sus parámetros, que tiene consecuencias reales. Tienes razón en que es un detalle irrelevante para arreglar el error que se plantea, pero no es cierto que sea un cambio que no vaya a cambiar nada, como dices. Es un problema que se debe corregir. Si te parece que las respuestas deben limitarse exclusivamente a lo que se está preguntando, vale, es respetable, pero creo que el otro extremo (contradecir la sugerencia y decir explícitamente que el cambio no hace nada) es igual de dañino.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es justo lo qeu me pasaba, y añadiendo que el metodo esta como no static asique me obligaba a instanciarlo para que funcione, el caso es que lo cambie a static, puse Provincia. y funciono, :)

Comment: @Racso, Estoy completamente de acuerdo en una cosa que has indicado! En que tenemos discrepancia de opiniones :). Estas basando tu último comentario en una suposición. Y si la pregunta de Cosoforo Decimo así lo indicase sabrías que lo que he dicho en mi respuesta pierde mucho sentido. Tu última frase... Si te soy sincero, no la entiendo. Me da a entender que limitar la respuesta exclusivamente a lo que se pregunta es tan dañino como el otro extremo. ¿Te refieres a dar una respuesta que no soluciona lo que se pregunta? La verdad es que no entiendo lo que quieres decir, lo siento.

Comment: @Cosoforo Decimo, me alegro de que hayas encontrado solución a tu problema! Esas cosas las verás más fácilmente según vayas cogiendo experiencia, no te preocupes! Un abrazo.

Comment: @Mario Castillo, Los dos extremos son "alargar las respuestas con temas que no vienen al caso" y "limitarse tanto a la pregunta hecha que se no sólo se ignoran otros problemas que puede haber en el planteamiento original, sino que se descartan de entrada sugerencias que los solucionan porque no tienen que ver con la pregunta". En este caso, descartaste el `public` con tanto énfasis que creo que el lector puede pensar que en realidad es una sugerencia inútil, cuando está lejos de serlo.

Comment: @CosoforoDecimo Si esta respuesta respondió tu pregunta, por favor márcala como Mejor Respuesta.

Comment: @Racso quería hacer hincapié en que el modificador public no es necesario en este caso en particular, porque es lo primero que se leia al entrar en la pregunta. Parece que tengo que aprender a medir mi énfasis, pero es que no puedo evitarlo! Lo vivo con esa intensidad :)